# SQL Query to provide a count of jobs that were open grouped by week, month, year for the last 12 months

Tags: sql, select, count

Given the following data:

```
Job      CreatedDate                ClosedDate
ID6      2014-06-04 01:51:47.060    NULL
ID7      2014-06-05 00:25:35.187    NULL
ID43     2014-06-16 05:17:18.803    2014-06-26 15:00:15.190
ID72     2014-06-20 04:00:07.733    2014-06-20 04:12:18.770
ID84     2014-06-27 16:01:18.953    NULL
ID74     2014-06-20 04:05:42.843    NULL
ID68     2014-06-20 03:46:52.653    2014-06-20 03:52:47.540
ID88     2014-07-03 03:47:55.407    NULL
ID64     2014-06-19 07:29:37.060    NULL
ID104    2014-07-08 02:59:58.337    2014-07-15 15:00:15.543
ID106    2014-07-08 03:02:29.710    2014-07-16 11:04:19.230
ID130    2014-07-10 04:30:20.900    NULL
ID132    2014-07-10 04:32:20.243    NULL
ID150    2014-07-15 20:59:06.077    2014-07-15 21:10:19.490
.
.
.
Etc.
```

I need to write a query that will group records by week, month, and year. A count of the number of records that were in an Open state at the end of each week (Sunday) needs to be returned.

The difficulty arises in determining if a job was in an Open state at the end of a particular week. I imagine the logic goes something like this: A job was open if the CreatedDate is less than or equal to the end of the week and the ClosedDate is after the end of the week or ClosedDate is NULL. A job can remain open over many weeks.

The output should look as follows.

```
Week    Month   Year    Count
 23       6     2014    80
 24       6     2014    36
 25       6     2014    71
 26       6     2014    0
 27       7     2014    25
 28       7     2014    180
```

So, at the end of week 23 there were 80 jobs that were still open. Where a week has no records the count should return 0. Only records that were created 12 months from the time the query is executed should be returned. The query is executed every week and used to build a rolling 12 month report. I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

I’ll give an example:

At the beginning of week 1 there are no jobs in the table. During week 1, 50 jobs are opened and 30 are closed which means that 20 are in an Open state at the end of the week.

During week 2, a further 50 jobs are opened and 40 are closed which means that 30 are in an Open state (when you add the 20 from last week and the 10 from this week) at the end of the week. Some of the jobs closed in week 2 were created in week 1 and some of the open jobs are still from week 1.

During week 3, a further 50 jobs are opened and 40 are closed which means that 40 are in an Open state at the end of the week. Some of the jobs closed in week 3 were created in weeks 1 and 2 and some of the open jobs are still from weeks 1 and 2.

And so on for a 12 month period.

When I run the query at the end of week 3 I want to know that at the end of week 1 there were 20 jobs open and at the end of week 2 there were 30 and at the end of week 3 there were 40. You can’t rely on the ClosedDate being NULL because even thought it was at the end of week 1 it may have been closed during week 3 and now has a ClosedDate. As I mentioned above, I think the logic that needs to be used is: A job was in the Open state at the end of a week if the CreatedDate is less than or equal to the end of the week and the ClosedDate is after the end of the week or ClosedDate is NULL.

So, at the end of week 3, when the query is run, the data that I would like to receive would look like:

```
Week    Month   Year    Count
 1       1     2014      20
 2       1     2014      30
 3       1     2014      40
```

A manual way of achieving what I need is to run a simple query at the end of each week that counts the number of jobs that have a ClosedDate of NULL. I then manually enter the week, month, year, and count into a table and use that table as a source for reporting. I was hoping that a more automated process could be achieved.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for..

```
DECLARE @S INT = (SELECT CAST(CAST(MIN([CREATEDDATE]) AS DATETIME) AS INT) FROM [DBO].[YOURTABLE] WHERE [CLOSEDDATE] IS NULL)
DECLARE @E INT = (SELECT CAST(CAST(MAX([CREATEDDATE]) AS DATETIME) AS INT) FROM [DBO].[YOURTABLE] WHERE [CLOSEDDATE] IS NULL)
DECLARE @TAB TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), DT DATETIME)

WHILE   @S <= @E
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @TAB
    SELECT  CAST(@S AS DATETIME)
SET @S = @S + 1
END

SELECT  MAIN.WEEK,Main.MONTH,Main.YEAR,
        LU.COUNT
FROM    (
        SELECT  DATEPART(YEAR,DT) YEAR, 
                DATEPART(MONTH,DT) MONTH, 
                DATEPART(WEEK,DT) WEEK 
        FROM    @TAB
        GROUP   BY DATEPART(YEAR,DT), 
                DATEPART(MONTH,DT), 
                DATEPART(WEEK,DT)) MAIN
LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT  DATEPART(YEAR,[CREATEDDATE]) YEAR, 
                DATEPART(MONTH,[CREATEDDATE]) MONTH, 
                DATEPART(WEEK,[CREATEDDATE]) WEEK,
                COUNT(*) COUNT
        FROM    [DBO].[YOURTABLE]
        WHERE   [CLOSEDDATE] IS NULL
        GROUP   BY  DATEPART(YEAR,[CREATEDDATE]), 
                DATEPART(MONTH,[CREATEDDATE]) , 
                DATEPART(WEEK,[CREATEDDATE])) LU
ON      MAIN.YEAR = LU.YEAR
AND     MAIN.MONTH = LU.MONTH
AND     MAIN.WEEK = LU.WEEK
ORDER   BY MAIN.YEAR,
        MAIN.MONTH,
        MAIN.WEEK
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Jithin, but it’s not quite what I’m looking for. It looks like your answer returns the number of jobs that were raised in a particular week that are still open (don’t have a CloseDate set). What I need is a bit more complex. I have updated the original post with more information. thanks